# Prevent swipe back on IOS ionic 5 Vue app

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vue-router

I have done it before with Ionic Angular for the entire app with:

```
IonicModule.forRoot({ swipeBackEnabled: false })
```

Or for a single page by injecting IonRouterOutlet:

```
this.routerOutlet.swipeGesture = true;
```

However, how can I perform this on an Ionic Vue app?

I disable global swiping with:

```
app.use(IonicVue, {swipeBackEnabled: false})
```

But if I import IonRouterOutlet on the page, it has no swipeGesture property, and I can't figure how to disable this option on a single page.

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this, will through a couple points in to see if this can be answered.

Answer (score 3):

iOS Only:
I have found a working but not beautiful approach.
First you import the createGesture function from @ionic/vue.

```
import { createGesture } from '@ionic/vue';
```

Then the standard swipe back gesture must be overwritten in the ionViewWillEnter.

```
const gesture = createGesture({
  el: document.getElementById('test'),
  threshold: 0,
  gestureName: 'goback-swipe',
  gesturePriority: 40.5, // priority of swipe to go back is 40
  onMove: ev => console.log(ev)
});
gesture.enable(true);
```

Then give the ion-page object an ID and apply the gesture to it.

```
<ion-page id="test">
```

Comment: Thanks, this also worked for me in React where I needed to stop go back on swipe for a sub navigation, I just changed the import to `@ionic/react` and wrapped it in an if for the `el` to keep TS happy.

Answer (score 2):

Phil0xFF thanks for your solution.

I created the `v-disable-swipe-back` directive based on your decision

Enjoy your use)

1. `npm i v-disable-swipe-back`
2. `<ion-page v-disable-swipe-back>`

Comment: Good one!!! :+1

Answer (score 1):

You can disable swipeGesture globally in your app by adding `[swipeGesture]="false"` to the `ion-router-outlet` in the `App.vue` file at the root of `src` :

```
<template>
  <ion-app>
    <Header />
    <ion-router-outlet [swipeGesture]="false" />
  </ion-app>
</template>
```

Comment: I get a`DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '[swipeGesture]' is not a valid attribute name.`

Comment: @CesarMartinezDominguez what is your ionic version ?